# CCC 2013 J4 NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, exception

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

 public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println(solution(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt()));


}

public static int solution(int totalMin, int chores) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] choresTime = new int[chores];
    int choresDone = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < chores; i++) {
        choresTime[i] = sc.nextInt();

    }

    // Sorting the Array's Values from Least to Greatest

    Arrays.sort(choresTime);

    for (int i = 0; i < choresTime.length; i++) {
        if (totalMin - choresTime[i] < 0) {
            break;

        } else {
            totalMin -= choresTime[i];
            choresDone++;

        }

    }

    return choresDone;

   }
}
```

Even though this code works perfectly fine on IntelliJ, I get a NoSuchElementException when I check my answer on DMOJ.

**Execution Results on DMOJ:**

Test case #1:   IR (java.util.NoSuchElementException)   [0.627s,    39.98 MB]   (0/10)

Test case #2:   IR (java.util.NoSuchElementException)   [0.546s,    39.15 MB]   (0/10)

Test case #3:   IR (java.util.NoSuchElementException)   [0.466s,    39.70 MB]   (0/10)

Test case #4:   IR (java.util.NoSuchElementException)   [0.445s,    39.64 MB]   (0/10)

Test case #5:   IR (java.util.NoSuchElementException)   [0.421s,    39.55 MB]   (0/10)

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I would add some print statements to make sure the values are what you think they are.

Comment: @JosephLarson That's what I did and it did work with the two test cases on IntelliJ. It just doesn't execute correctly on DMOJ for some reason.

Comment: Do you know WHERE you're getting the exceptions? Which line of code? I don't know anything about DMOJ. I suspect they're feeding data you're not expecting. When you run things on DMOJ, do you get to see the output? You can add lots of print statements to figure out what is crashing where. That will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring more than one `Scanner` in your code. Generally, it is not good to have two `Scanner` objects, as it could cause problems. In this case, it seems that Java is closing the first `Scanner` object, which is in turn closing `System.in`, so the second `Scanner` cannot read from it.  Placing the `Scanner` outside of the `main` method (`static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`) and deleting the second scanner gives me AC on the problem.

https://dmoj.ca/submission/3307266